# looping through a set of regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop

I have a set of regular expressions stored in an object, along the style of

```
myRegexes = {};
myRegexes.reg1 = /[a-z]+[0-9]+/;
myRegexes.reg2 = /[a-e]+/;
```

I can then do  `myRegexes.reg1.exec(sampleStr)`  and it works perfectly fine.

However, if I loop through this object and say

```
for( reg in myRegexes ){
    reg.exec(sampleStr);
}
```

I get an exception saying "TypeError: Object reg1 has no method 'exec'"

I know that javascript is wonky with how it does for-in loops, but I don't see how it successfully finds the variable, but loses its methods along the way. Can anyone tell me why this fails and what the right way to do it is?

Comment: JavaScript is not really wonky with for loops. It just doesn't do what you think it does :)

Comment: I was thinking of instances where you should use hasOwnProperty to avoid undesired artifacts. In this case, I was just failing to understand the basics.

Comment: The key here is in how Javascript treats members of an object; they're basically hash keys, so when you loop over them, you treat them as such.  The answers below give more details, but that's the gist.  Defining an object's properties is equivalent to creating a hash table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reg` refers to the property name, you have to grab the actual regex object:

```
for( reg in myRegexes ) {
  myRegexes[ reg ].exec(sampleStr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`for-in`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) enumerates properties of an object, `reg` being the property name (a string) not the property value (your regex). Use

```
for (reg in myRegexes)
    myRegexes[reg].exec(sampleStr);
```